# mixed up de-referencing forms of pointers in an array of pointers to struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a function where i pass to it an array of pointers to structure as an argument
`void BubbleSort_ArrayOfEmployees(struct employee* emp_arr[],int size);`
why i can't De-referencing any pointer of the array using this form `(*(emp_arr[i]).id)` the compiler state this error `//error: request for member 'id' in something not a structure or union|` while if i use `emp_arr[i]->id` form of De-referencing the code runs smoothly giving the expexted results

aren't both forms the same ?

p.s i can upload the full function and structure if it will make it easier for anyone to try it

Comment: `emp_arr[i]` is a pointer, you can't use `.` operator on a pointer. Maybe you meant `emp_arr[i]->id` ?

Comment: that is why i added * before the pointer for dereferencing it before i can use . the wrong thing i did has been fixed up in the comment below, u can check it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` operator has higher precedence than `*`, so you need to change your parentheses.

```
(*emp_arr[i]).id
```